# [pickerView reloadAllComponents]; doesn't update UIPickerView component width

Tags: components, width, uipickerview

I have 2 columnes in UIPicerView, and when I call `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]` it doesn't call

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

for updating components widths, but when a switch in program 2=>3 and 3=>2 mthod calling, i must change current columnt count and than call `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller should inherit the UIPickerView protocol. Than implement

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

method